# Iconic fonts displayed partially in IE9-10

Tags: fonts, internet-explorer-9, font-face, internet-explorer-10

We're having an issue with IE rendering only part of the characters in a font. This only happens in production and the same font file works great locally. It would be great if someone could give me a hand on this! Thanks!

P.S. The font is generated by IcoMoon

You can see it yourself [on the preview page here](https://level.travel/preview/icons).

[image]

UPDATE: Disabling Amazon Cloundfront CDN helped me avoid this issue. Although it would be really nice if we could eliminate it once and for all.